# Does Google Cloud Functions support code compilation with Python 3.7 runtime?

Tags: google-cloud-functions

I'm attempting to get some code running in Google Cloud Functions with the Python 3.7 runtime. Function deploy is failing when I include scipy in my requirements.txt. I'm guessing this is because scipy contains C code that needs compilation, but I can't find anything in the documentation about support for code compilation.

Do all of dependencies have to be pure-python code? If so, would it be possible to include a binary version of the lib instead?

Comment: [Google Cloud Functions supports Python 3.7 runtime](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/concepts/python-runtime). I was able to get a function to deploy and execute with SciPy in my library. Perhaps you could share your code and requirements file and we can take a closer look?

Comment: @ChristopherP hmmm... I'm suspicious that it might be a version issue. I'm going to try some different version combinations and see what happens.